# DataTable is empty from calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes in a table value parameter. When I test the procedure with the table value parameter in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 I get the correct values returned.

```
declare @NumberList as dbo.NumberList

insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101197);
insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101196);
insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101194);
insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101042);
insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101190);
insert into @NumberList(value) values (16101191);

--select value from @NumberList

exec GetClientLeadsByClientId @NumberList
```

However, in my C# code the `DataTable` is empty. The `clientIds` match the values above when I test it in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
private DataTable GetClientLeadsByClientIds(List<int> clientIds)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var numberList = AddClientIdsToNumberListTemporaryTable(clientIds);
    var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("GetClientLeadsByClientId", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure } )
    using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        var parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@NumberList";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        parameter.Value = numberList;
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

I use this method to create the table value parameter.

```
private DataTable AddClientIdsToNumberListTemporaryTable(List<int> clientIds)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable("NumberList");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < clientIds.Count; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(clientIds[i]);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `parameter` to `command.Parameters` collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parameter you created to the command.

```
using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@NumberList";
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    parameter.Value = numberList;

    //ADD THIS
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the typename to the parameter? I'm surprised it would work without it.

```
parameter.TypeName = "NumberList";
```

Comment: It is not needed if you pass the parameter into a stored procedure because the stored procedure defines the type of the parameter.